# Expo contacts native modal

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, contacts, expo, react-native-contacts

On [this Medium article "Expo SDK v29.0.0 is now available"](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v29-0-0-is-now-available-f001d77fadf), it is said that

> You can now present native modals for creating, and editing, and inspecting contacts.

with an animated GIF below of the contacts as if it was the OS contact displaying.

However, I see in the doc the API to access the Contacts, no problem, but I don't see anything related to display a native Modal with Contacts, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that is the iOS only function [presentFormAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/contacts/#presentformasync).

Fwiw the project I maintain [react-native-contacts](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts) has support for this on Android and iOS.
See https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts#open-contact-form

Comment: yeah I saw your lib, looks like a very nice job but I wanted to custom the way I display the contact (add a 'validate' button for example), and it didn't seem to be feasible with your lib, is it ?

Comment: I was too bad at that time to realize that your lib is only the API to get contact, not to display them, so it's perfect, I switch to it. Thanks !